# eclipse can't find android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Even after clicking on Add Support Library and choosing version 19, eclipse still can't find android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout. Does anyone know how to get this to work? I am using

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I am working on a mac mavericks computer with Juno.

**update: import section**

```
import java.util.Observer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;//red underline
```

**Update**

By the way, I don't know if this matters: this is an Appengine Connected Android Project, which I build using Google-Eclipse-Plugin

**Update 3:**

It's looking like the Android Support Library 19.1.0 is not available through the SDK Manager. How else might I obtain it?

Comment: show us your import section... maybe you forgot to import the widget.

Comment: @Vyger eclipse red underlines my import `import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;` I restarted eclipse to no avail. Also when I look on the available list after `android.support.v4.widget.`, sure enough `SwipeRefreshLayout` is not an option. so I must somehow have the wrong support library.

Comment: Note that `SwipeRefreshLayout` is in v19.1 of the library. Are you sure that is what you added, and not v19.0.1?

Comment: When I go to `Android Tools > Add Support Library` I click on the one option that is provided: version 19. How do I get something else/more such as v19.0.1? @CommonsWare. Also my libs folder only has the one support library (deleted before adding it to make sure). Also the support library works fine with my Fragments, etc

Comment: @Vyger I have added import section

Comment: Use your SDK Manager and see what version you have downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out the library is in the following location

```
/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/19.1.0
```

As opposed to the usual

```
/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support
```

Also I had to restart eclipse and go to `Android SDK Manager` over and over and over, until the 19.1.0 version shows up.

I hope this saves someone else some trouble.

Answer (score 18):

It was difficult to update the support library to version 19.1 so i downloaded it manually from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.1.zip and added the jar to my build path manually. works for me. I dont know why the 19 update shows instead of 19.1.0

Comment: I tried everything in this thread (as well as others) with no luck.  This answer worked instantly.  Thanks MYK

Comment: for people (like me) who had trouble adding it to the in eclipse build path, do this:

Using Eclipse

Create a libs/ directory in the root of your application project.

Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., <sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar) into your application's project libs/ directory.

Right click the JAR file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

Answer (score 3):

The SDK Manager update Android Support Library to 19.1.0. 
But when you use Android Tools > Add Support Library, eclipse update Android Support Library to 19.0. I think this is a bug. Copy Android Support Library 19.1.0 to libs folder manually.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you don't have the android-support-**v4**.jar in Java Build Path. Add it from the android-support-v7-appcompat.

Comment: If that were the case, why would `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;` work? It's only failing for `import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;`

Comment: I didn't notice that. Are you sure you are using the correct version of the v4? I would remove all libraries from Eclipse and add them again.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, even though you may include `v4 support library` or you may have `v7-appcompat` included in your project, you may not be able to import `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

You need to make sure that

- you change the `target=android-19` to `target=android-22`(It should be anything greater that 19) and
- manually import : `import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;` in your activity which will resolve the import related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with old project. But when I create new project, Eclipse can find this import.

Comment: What do you mean? Delete project and then create from existing source? This is not the kind of project I can just recreate from scratch. Also it's a Appengine Connected Android Project.

Comment: Try to copy library from new test project to your old project (replace jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with updating support library from eclipse: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67991

Just update it by starting Android SDK manager manually and add new v4 lib to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for tehnolog's tips. 
Update to 19.1 by follow above link -> create new project and import android.support.v4 library -> simply copy android.support.v4.jar to old project's libs folder, Add To BuildPath. SwipeRefreshLayout will appear :D

Answer (score 0):

In `androidx`, add

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

inorder to use `SwipeRefreshLayout`