# Can't find SwipeRefreshLayout in xml

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to add a swipe/pull to refresh to my app

In the code there are no problem i can use the view from **android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout**

BUT in the xml i can't use it

My project use **support.v4 version 19.1** and android **api9** to **api19**

What am i missing ?

Comment: Check your Support.V4.jar properly configure or not...

Comment: my project is ok i use support V4 for others things like actionbar, fragments... i already tried to re-import it from scratch

Comment: Have you tried manually downloading the lib as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416053/could-not-find-class-android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout

Comment: yes i tried to get it from the website and from the bundle (i use ADT)