# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol 'SwipeRefreshLayout'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm now using Android Studio 3.1.1 and the `build.gradle` looks imported these:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```

But when I try to use `import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;` to use SwipeRefreshLayout, it said *Cannot resolve symbol 'SwipeRefreshLayout'*.

I have tried the following solutions:

- Reinstall Androd SDK
- Delete the .gradle folder and build again
- "Invalidate Caches and restart" from File menu of Android Studio
- Clean and rebuild the project

But still get the same problem.

The code I am using like this:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

static SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

public HomeFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refresh();
        }
    });

    refresh();

    return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: share your code where it is use

Comment: https://www.appsinfoway.com/implementing-swipe-to-refresh-android/

Comment: Share your code how your are using ...!

Comment: for androidx, read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58453899/7356355

Comment: could please mark my answer as an answer?

Answer (score 23):

**Add this dependency into your gradle file:**

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 5):

For me this was solved by using
`androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` instead.

like this:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

with dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
```

See the official guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface)

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need to add `support-v4` if you have added `appcompat-v7` This library depends on the v4 Support Library. so no worry about *Cannot resolve symbol* just go to File-> Invalidate catches/Restart-> Invalidate and Restart or Clear project by Buld->Clean Project from Menu

> Check official doc https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html